# My Chrome extension with no error in the code

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I created a chrome extension to sort the result on nike.com sale page to sort the item by the biggest sale.

There is no error when I run the code, however, when I try to run the extension when I am on the sale page, the button is greyed out.

I am not really sure where to look as I can't see any erro anywhere.

Below you will find my two files

manifest.js

```
{
  "name": "Nike Sort Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Sorts Nike.com sale section by biggest percentage off original price.",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "host_permissions": ["https://www.nike.com/w/*"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.nike.com/w/sale-*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The second one called content.js is below.

```
// Get the list of products on the page
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.product-card')

// Create an array to hold the product information
let productData = []

// Loop through each product and get its information
products.forEach(product => {
  // Get the product title
  const title = product.querySelector('.product-card__title').innerText

  // Get the product price
  const price = product.querySelector('.product-price__wrapper').innerText

  // Get the product discount
  const discountElement = product.querySelector('.product-card__percent')
  let discount = 0
  if (discountElement) {
    discount = parseInt(discountElement.innerText)
  }

  // Add the product information to the array
  productData.push({
    title: title,
    price: price,
    discount: discount
  })
})

// Sort the products by discount (largest to smallest)
productData.sort((a, b) => b.discount - a.discount)

// Loop through the sorted products and add them back to the page in the new order
products.forEach((product, index) => {
  product.querySelector('.product-card__title').innerText = productData[index].title
  product.querySelector('.product-price__wrapper').innerText = productData[index].price
  if (productData[index].discount > 0) {
    if (product.querySelector('.product-card__percent')) {
      product.querySelector('.product-card__percent').innerText = productData[index].discount + '% off'
      product.querySelector('.product-card__percent').remove();
    }
  } else {
    if (product.querySelector('.product-card__percent')) {
      product.querySelector('.product-card__percent').remove()
    }
  }
})
```

I am not sure what to do next as I can't see any error in the code.

Comment: Errors in the `content.js` file will appear in the console of any `https://www.nike.com/w/sale-*` page. If there are no errors. Most probably, `products` is an empty `NodeList`,  there are no `.product-card` in the DOM when your content script runs.

Comment: Debug your code in devtools debugger. Set breakpoints and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check your variables in DevTools.

> Note: Reloading the extension and the web page is mandatory if you change the program.

```js
// Get the list of products on the page
const products = document.querySelectorAll('.product-card')
console.log(products)
```

[image]